# Unit Testing (assert.h) on Beaglebone Black (ARM) with Linux Headers installed on SD Card

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, kernel, arm

Ok so here it goes:

I'm developing a DMA Kernel Driver on the Beaglebone Black (ARM Cortex-A8) - currently my file system looks like this (important for the question):

```
/dev/mmcblk1p2  1.7G  1.1G  511M  69% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            247M  4.0K  247M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  224K   50M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            248M     0  248M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk1p1   71M   20M   52M  28% /boot/uboot
/dev/mmcblk0p1  3.6G  571M  2.8G  17% /media/microsd
```

**rootfs** and **/boot** are sitting on the eMMC NAND Flash Memory Chip

mounting **/media/microsd** to give myself an extra ~4GB of space

My driver code base is sitting in `__/home/user/__`
the Linux Headers were too big to install on `__rootfs__` (NAND Flash) so I wrote a little script that installed them to the `__/media_microsd__` filesystem, then symbolically linked `__/lib/modules/3.8.13-bone28/build__` to `__/media/microsd/usr/src/linux-3.8.13-bone28__` then in my makefile I run this: `__make -C /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone28/build M=$(PWD) modules__` so that the driver is built where the linux headers are living (/media/microsd ...) and then I can include them easily within my code by doing `#include <linux/whatever.h>`

code Reference: [GitHub - Mighty_DMA](https://github.com/theqlabs/mighty_dma)

**My issue comes when trying to build Unit Tests** using the `#include <assert.h>` header file which lives in `/usr/include` ... since my Makefile uses the -C flag to change immediately to the SD card directory (to access Linux Headers and Build) then Make tries to look for `assert.h` in `/media/microsd/usr/include` instead of `/usr/include/`

**What is the best way to build Unit Tests using either Check (`check.h`) or Assert (`assert.h`) when I can not include them in my code because of the divergence of the file systems living on both NAND Flash and SD Card**

I have tried modifying AutoTools and Makefiles to include the directory path `/usr/include/` but because the -C flag, it becomes relative. I tried giving `#include </usr/include/assert.h>` direct path to the file but that doesn't solve the problem recursively - **it will begin to error about header files assert calls ... and so on**

Thank you in advance for your help, I really don't know what the best route to take is here.

<3,

-q

Comment: Use [bind mounts](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) instead of symlinks (e.g. `mount -o bind /media/microsd/usr/src/linux-3.8.13-bone28 /usr/src/linux-3.8.13-bone28` and so on). All you need to do is create an empty directory on the root filesystem, and you can bind-mount its contents (including any subdirectories) from anywhere else.